# C++11 Cereal Serialization - versioning

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, versioning, cereal

I have successfully serialized two members of my class.

```cpp
    archive(
        cereal::make_nvp("width", m_width),
        cereal::make_nvp("height", m_height),
    );
```

Now, in a later version my code contains more members and I would like to archive them as well:

```cpp
    archive(
        cereal::make_nvp("width", m_width),
        cereal::make_nvp("height", m_height),
        cereal::make_nvp("lambda0", m_lambda0),
        cereal::make_nvp("phi1", m_phi1)
    );
```

However, this crashes as the new members are not present in old archives. As far as I know there is no way of having default values defined for these variables in `make_nvp`.

But there for sure has to be some kind of versioning so that this default circumstance can be solved? Could someone point me to the documentation of this or even better to some sample code? I can't find anything on there official [website](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/index.html). ( But most likely I am just blind .. )

Comment: https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/transition_from_boost.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference - here it is documented how to version:

https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_functions.html#versioning